# How to send two variables in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to send data from google sheet using API. I need to send two variables payload and payload1 in line payload: JSON.stringify(payload)

```
function sendDataToRoistatAPI() {
  var url = "https:/XXX";
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Users"); 

  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    var rowData = data[i];
    var payload = {
      manual_custom_metric_id: 2,
      source: rowData[1],
      value: rowData[2],
      period: JSON.parse(rowData[4]),
    };
    var payload1 = {
      manual_custom_metric_id: 3,
      source: rowData[1],
      value: rowData[3],
      period: JSON.parse(rowData[4]),
    };
    //Logger.log(payload);
    //Logger.log(payload1);
    var options = {
      method: "post",
      contentType: "application/json",
      payload: JSON.stringify(payload)
    };

    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);

    Logger.log(response.getContentText()); }
```

In payload and payload1 I write different kind of data, but cells B and D are the same

What I tried

```
payload: JSON.stringify([payload, payload1])
```

and also

```
var options1 = {
      method: "post",
      contentType: "application/json",
      payload: JSON.stringify(payload1)
    };

    var response1 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options1);

    Logger.log(response1.getContentText());
```

but it didn't help

Comment: can't able to understand your requirement could you please elaborate it

Comment: @NodeDeveloper edited. Hope that will help

Comment: could please provide me the sample output of what you need and also inspect the network tab to check how the payload are passing

Comment: In order to correctly understand your situation, can you provide the information on your current Spreadsheet?

Comment: Does the api support two variables? If so, quote the relevant api documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of objects and send that array as a payload.

For example:

```
function sendDataToRoistatAPI() {
  var url = "https:/XXX";
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Users");

  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  var combinedPayloads = [];

  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    var rowData = data[i];
    var payload = {
      manual_custom_metric_id: 2,
      source: rowData[1],
      value: rowData[2],
      period: JSON.parse(rowData[4]),
    };
    var payload1 = {
      manual_custom_metric_id: 3,
      source: rowData[1],
      value: rowData[3],
      period: JSON.parse(rowData[4]),
    };

    combinedPayloads.push(payload);
    combinedPayloads.push(payload1);
  }

  var options = {
    method: "post",
    contentType: "application/json",
    payload: JSON.stringify(combinedPayloads),
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);

  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}
```

**Update:**
Try this once

```
var options = {
  method: "post",
  contentType: "application/json",
  payload: JSON.stringify(payload),
};

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
Logger.log(response.getContentText());

// Sending payload1
var options1 = {
  method: "post",
  contentType: "application/json",
  payload: JSON.stringify(payload1),
};

var response1 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options1);
Logger.log(response1.getContentText());
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help. Only payload is sent

Comment: You can call `UrlFetchApp.fetch` two times to pass two payloads. Check the updated section.

Comment: still doesn't help